# How to use enum value in checkbox and store the accourding in integer number?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, checkbox, enums, razor-pages

I have a string property that corresponds have some checkbox values. I want to use an enum. Enum values want to store on that string property.

My property is in the Model class. It has many properties. I just put only two properties and enum:

```
public class Client_CIPEnergyCrisis
{

    [Display(Name = "What type of assistance are you seeking?")]
    public string AssistanceType { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public List<int> AssistanceTypeList { get; set; }
}

public enum AssistanceTypes
{
    [Display(Name = "Assistance with Disconnection")]
    AssistanceWithDisconnection = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Utility Pole/ Gas line Hookup or Deposit")]
    UtilityGaslineHookup = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Emergency Heating Fuel")]
    EmergencyHeatingFuel = 3,

    [Display(Name = "System Repair or Replacement")]
    SystemRepair = 4,

    [Display(Name = "Anything else ?")]
    Anything = 5,
}
```

This is my view page. That is a partial view. It's used for Insert and Update data.

```
@model Client_CIPEnergyCrisis

<div><label asp-for="AssistanceType" class="form-label"></label></div>

@foreach (var assistanceType in Enum.GetValues<AssistanceTypes>())
{
    <div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)assistanceType)" name="AssistanceTypeList">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => assistanceType) </label>
    </div>
}
```

This is my Add Razor Page add.cshtml page. Here have multiple partial views. We can ignore it. We are passed the needed model.

```
  @page
@model AddCIPEnergyCrisisModel


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CIP Energy Crisis";
}

<partial name="_DataFormTitlePartial" model='new string("New CIP Energy Crisis")' />

<div class="card dataForm mb-3">
    <form method="post">
        <partial name="_FamilyIncomeInfoPartial" model="@Model.FamilyIncomeList" />
        <partial name="_CIPEnergyCrisisPartial" model="@Model.CIPEnergyCrisis" />
        <partial name="_SaveCancelPartial" model="@Model.CCInfo" />
    </form>
</div>**strong text**
```

This is add.cshtml.cs Page.

```
 [BindProperty]
     public List<int> AssistanceTypeList { get; set; }
    
     [BindProperty]
     public Client_CIPEnergyCrisis CIPEnergyCrisis { get; set; }
     public IActionResult OnPost()
            { var selectedAssistantType = string.Join(",", AssistanceTypeList);
                    CIPEnergyCrisis.AssistanceType = selectedAssistantType;
    }
```

Add feature work well. But when I go to edit. then I face the problem.

This is my Edit Razor Page edit.cshtml.cs page. Here have multiple partial views. We can ignore it. We are passed the needed model.

```
 public void OnGet(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                CIPEnergyCrisis = new Client_CIPEnergyCrisis();
                var data = serviceManager.GetClient_CIPEnergyCrisis(Id);

                var selectedAssistantType = data.AssistanceType;

                CIPEnergyCrisis.AssistanceTypeList = selectedAssistantType
                    .Split(",")
                    .Select(int.Parse)
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
```

Maybe I need a if condition in partial page. But I can't do that. may you help me please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First approach:

You can bind the selected checkbox values to a list of integers then convert the list to comma separated string inside `OnPost` method. Notice that the name attribute of the checkboxes `name="AssistanceTypeList"` has the same name as the bound property `public List<int> AssistanceTypeList { get; set; }`. This is important.

**Page:**

```html
<div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)AssistanceTypes.AssistanceWithDisconnection)" name="AssistanceTypeList"
           checked="@(Model.AssistanceTypeList.Contains((int)AssistanceTypes.AssistanceWithDisconnection))">

    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> Assistance with Disconnection </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)AssistanceTypes.UtilityGaslineHookup)" name="AssistanceTypeList"
           checked="@(Model.AssistanceTypeList.Contains((int)AssistanceTypes.UtilityGaslineHookup))">

    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> Utility Pole/ Gas line Hookup or Deposit </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)AssistanceTypes.EmergencyHeatingFuel)" name="AssistanceTypeList"
           checked="@(Model.AssistanceTypeList.Contains((int)AssistanceTypes.EmergencyHeatingFuel))">

    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> Emergency Heating Fuel </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)AssistanceTypes.SystemRepair)" name="AssistanceTypeList"
           checked="@(Model.AssistanceTypeList.Contains((int)AssistanceTypes.SystemRepair))">

    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> System Repair or Replacement </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)AssistanceTypes.Anything)" name="AssistanceTypeList"
           checked="@(Model.AssistanceTypeList.Contains((int)AssistanceTypes.Anything))">

    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> Anything else ?  </label>
</div>
```

**PageModel:**

```
[BindProperty]
public List<int> AssistanceTypeList { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    var selectedAssistantType = data.AssistanceType;
        
    AssistanceTypeList = selectedAssistantType
        .Split(",")
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .ToList();
}

public void OnPost()
{
    // AssistanceTypeList contains the enum values that where checked by the user. We just need to convert the list to comma separated string.
    
    var selectedAssistantType = string.Join(",", AssistanceTypeList);
}
```

### **Second approach (my recommendation):**

First of all use the `Display` attribute to set the display name for each enum value. The display name will be shown inside the `label` of each checkbox.

```
public enum AssistanceTypes
{
    [Display(Name = "Assistance with Disconnection")]
    AssistanceWithDisconnection = 0,

    [Display(Name = "Utility Pole/ Gas line Hookup or Deposit")]
    UtilityGaslineHookup = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Emergency Heating Fuel")]
    EmergencyHeatingFuel = 2,

    [Display(Name = "System Repair or Replacement")]
    SystemRepair = 3,

    [Display(Name = "Anything else ?")]
    Anything = 4,
}
```

Inside your Page, instead of creating each checkbox "manually", iterate the `AssistanceTypes` values and create a checkbox for each value. Use `@Html.DisplayFor` html helper to get the friendly display names for the labels.

```html
@foreach (var assistanceType in Enum.GetValues<AssistanceTypes>())
{
    <div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)assistanceType)" name="AssistanceTypeList"
               checked="@(Model.AssistanceTypeList.Contains((int)assistanceType))">

        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => assistanceType) </label>
    </div>
}
```

The `PageModel` stays the same.

This way if in the future you need to add new values to the `AssistanceTypes` enum. You don't need to change anything in your Page and `PageModel`.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes#binding-to-collections

### How to use inside a partial example:

**_AssistanceTypePartial.cshtml:**

```
@model List<int>

@foreach (var assistanceType in Enum.GetValues<AssistanceTypes>())
{
    <div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="@((int)assistanceType)" name="AssistanceTypeList"
               checked="@(Model.Contains((int)assistanceType))">

        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => assistanceType) </label>
    </div>
}
```

**Inside your view page:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 row ">
    <partial name="_AssistanceTypePartial"
             model="@Model.AssistanceTypeList">

    <div class="col-md-4 pt-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Explain" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But when I want to edit than those places where I have checked it should show checked again.

Comment: At first, I catch the value <" var selectedAssistant = data.AssistanceType; ", >
Then try to split by comma <" var selectedAssistantType = selectedAssistant.Split(","); ">
Then try to convert a int list <"var AssistantType = selectedAssistantType.Select(int.Parse).ToList();"> 
At last, try to assign list in object property, but I can't <" CIPEnergyCrisis.AssistanceType = AssistantType;">

What is the procedure to get checked value again

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to populate the `List<int>` property with the previously selected values (I think you already did that correctly). You also have to set the `checked` attribute to the `input` element based on if the list contains the enum value.

Comment: Sorry to say that, I just follow approach, that's why not use first one.

Comment: But i can't use if condition in view page. It’s not work.

Comment: I'm using partial view.  That why i can't  get any value, maybe you can understand what i'm saying.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get a condition?  That i used cheked

Comment: You can pass a model to a partial view. If you are using the Partial tag helper this is how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model

Comment: Hey, It needs a condition for checked or unchecked. But I couldn't understand

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have so far so I can tell you what is missing?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question

Comment: Simply add this `checked="@(Model.AssistanceTypeList.Contains((int)assistanceType))"` to the input element.

Comment: I solved it in different ways, Thank you

Comment: Do you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: OK, I'm Sharing my solution.